# Does a function with these properties exist?

Tags: functions

For $x_1, x_2, x_3 \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, does there exist a function $f(\cdot)$ defined on $\mathbb{Z}^+$, not necessarily continuous or differentiable, such that:

$$f(x_1) > f(x_2) \\ f(x_2) > f(x_3) \\ f(x_3) > f(x_1) $$

My immediate thought is that no such function exists, since a function can only be a many-to-one or one-to-one relation, and the above would require a one-to-many relation. If so, is there a more formal way of showing that the above is impossible? Or is it trivial to observe?

If I am wrong and such a function does exist, what is an example of one?

Comment: An interesting aside: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nontransitive_dice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function has exactly one output.

If such a function exists, by transitivity, we would have $f(x_1) > f(x_1)$ which is a contradiction.